# Keyboard Hook only recognizing Caps Lock?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

Since I was dumb and bought a keyboard that didn't have any indicator lights, I decided to write up a quick program to popup the statuses of Caps, Scroll and Num Lock.

I decided on WinForms because that's what I'm comfortable with, and my main form class looks like such:

```
globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

    public Indicators()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CheckKeyCaps()
    {
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = (IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)) ? "Caps Lock: ON" : "Caps Lock: OFF";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
    }

    public void CheckKeyScroll()
    {
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = (IsKeyLocked(Keys.Scroll)) ? "Scroll Lock: ON" : "Scroll Lock: OFF";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
    }

    public void CheckKeyNum()
    {
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) ? "Num Lock: ON" : "Num Lock: OFF";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
    }

    private void IndicatorsLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Scroll);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.CapsLock);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumLock);
        gkh.KeyUp += gkh_KeyUp;
        Visible = false;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
    }

    public void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Scroll:
                CheckKeyScroll();
                break;
            case Keys.CapsLock:
                CheckKeyCaps();
                break;
            case Keys.NumLock:
                CheckKeyNum();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I utilized [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) to add the keyboard hook, and now it only will toggle the popups for the CapsLock key. Pressing Num or Scroll Lock will only cause the popup to display "Scroll Lock: ON" or "Num Lock: ON".

I've tried running through the debugger with breakpoints on the switch, the event handler, and I can't make heads or tails of it. I'm relatively new (6 months) to programming, so I'm assuming that I have made an error somewhere, but I'm not savvy enough to figure out where.

Comment: Where is the code of IsKeyLocked? Everything seems related to the return value of this method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why you're calling [`Control.IsKeyLocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx) if you've installed a hook to provide you notification of keyboard events. Why not just get the information from the hook notification?